# How to debug exceptions in TCP connection when App is restarted?

Tags: tcp, spring-integration

I have an application that uses Spring Integration to send messages to a vendor application over TCP and receive and process responses. The vendor sends messages without a length header or an message-ending token and the message contains carriage returns so I have implemented a custom deserializer. The messages are sent as XML strings so I have to process the input stream, looking for a specific closing tag to know when the message is complete.  The application works as expected until the vendor application is restarted or a port switch occurs on my application, at which time the CPU usage on my application spikes and the application becomes unresponsive. The application throws a SocketException: `o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Send Failed; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed` when the socket closes. I have set the SocketTimeout to be 1 minute.

Here is the connection factory implementation:

```
    @Bean
    public AbstractClientConnectionFactory tcpConnectionFactory() {
        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory factory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(this.serverIp,
                Integer.parseInt(this.port));

        return getAbstractClientConnectionFactory(factory, keyStoreName, trustStoreName,
                keyStorePassword, trustStorePassword, hostVerify);
    }

    private AbstractClientConnectionFactory getAbstractClientConnectionFactory(
            TcpNetClientConnectionFactory factory, String keyStoreName, String trustStoreName,
            String keyStorePassword, String trustStorePassword, boolean hostVerify) {

        TcpSSLContextSupport sslContextSupport = new DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport(keyStoreName,
                trustStoreName, keyStorePassword, trustStorePassword);
        DefaultTcpNetSSLSocketFactorySupport tcpSocketFactorySupport =
                new DefaultTcpNetSSLSocketFactorySupport(sslContextSupport);
        factory.setTcpSocketFactorySupport(tcpSocketFactorySupport);
        factory.setTcpSocketSupport(new DefaultTcpSocketSupport(hostVerify));
        factory.setDeserializer(new MessageSerializerDeserializer());
        factory.setSerializer(new MessageSerializerDeserializer());
        factory.setSoKeepAlive(true);
        factory.setSoTimeout(60000);

        return factory;
    }
```

Here is the deserialize method:

```
    private String readUntil(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        String s = "";
        byte[] closingTag = CLOSING_MESSAGE_TAG.getBytes(ASCII);
        try {
            Integer bite;
            while (true) {
                bite = inputStream.read();
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(bite);
                byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                int start = bytes.length - closingTag.length;
                if (start > closingTag.length) {
                    byte[] subarray = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, start, bytes.length);
                    if (Arrays.equals(subarray, closingTag)) {
                        s = new String(bytes, ASCII);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            logger.error("Expected SocketTimeoutException thrown");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception thrown when deserializing message {}", s);
            throw e;
        }

        return s;
    }
```

Any help in identifying the cause of the CPU spike or a suggested fix would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT #1**
Adding serialize method.

```
    @Override
    public void serialize(String string, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(string) && StringUtils.startsWith(string, OPENING_MESSAGE_TAG) &&
                StringUtils.endsWith(string, CLOSING_MESSAGE_TAG)) {

            outputStream.write(string.getBytes(UTF8));
            outputStream.flush();
        }
    }
```

the inbound-channel-adapter uses the ConnectionFactory

```
<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="tcpInboundChannelAdapter"          
    channel="inboundReceivingChannel"
    connection-factory="tcpConnectionFactory"
    error-channel="errorChannel"
/>
```

**EDIT #2**
Outbound Channel Adapter

```
<int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter
            id="tcpOutboundChannelAdapter"
            channel="sendToTcpChannel"
            connection-factory="tcpConnectionFactory"/>
```

**Edit #3**
We have added in the throw for the Exception and are still seeing the CPU spike, although it is not as dramatic. Could we still be receiving bytes from socket in the inputStream.read() method? The metrics seem to indicate that the read method is consuming server resources.

---

@Artem Bilan Thank you for your continued feedback on this. My server metrics seem to indicate that they deserialize method is what is consuming the CPU. I was thinking that the SendFailed error occurs because of the vendor restarting their application.

Thus far, I have been unable to replicate this issue other than in production. The only exception I can find in production logs is the SocketException mentioned above.

Thank you.

Comment: I think the deserializer has nothing to do with that error. The `send` is a serializer part, so you probably need to show that one instead of `readUntil`. Also, would you mind to share what is your flow? How do you use that `tcpConnectionFactory`? Any chances to see more of your stack trace? The spike probably goes from the retry you may have around your sending service. Therefore something like simple reproducible sample would be great to have for investigation on our side.

Comment: Added Edit 1 information that you have requested. Thanks again.

Comment: The `<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter>` is for inbound messages. You fail on the outbound. See that error - `Send Failed`. So, you showed wrong code again.

Comment: @ArtemBilan. I have added an additional edit. thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Well, consider to throw that `SocketTimeoutException` instead of just `logger.error()`. This way the connection will know that it is not valid any more and will try to reconnect.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I will try that. thank you again.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I have added the throw clause but we are still seeing the CPU spike. Please see Edit #3 above.

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you use one of out-of-the-box deserializers: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-codecs ? How about that `ByteArraySingleTerminatorSerializer` instead of your custom one?

Comment: unfortunately the vendor does not send a terminating byte. it is an XML string that we have to read to find a closing tag.

Comment: Well, see the logic in the `ByteArrayCrLfSerializer`. Probably you can make similar logic for your closing XML tag.

Comment: @ArtemBilan, our business partner was able to change on their side to send the single terminator character. we have changed our side to use that and things have worked well in prod. Thank you again for your help. I am not sure how to accept your answer though.

Comment: I think you just create an answer yourself and you even can accept it. Since I gave you only clues and you have fixed everything yourself, it is probably better and easier for you to summarize it and answer to help others.